# C++ How to fix error "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue"?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have an compiling error in my project "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue".
I read about it but most question is about passing value as argument to function.

Code in Component.cpp

```cpp
    const FrameData* Animation::GetCurrentFrame() const
    {
        if (frames.size() > 0)
        {
            return &frames[currentFrameIndex];
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    void CAnimation::Update(float deltaTime)
    {
        FrameData& data = currentAnimation.second->GetCurrentFrame(); //**ERROR IS HERE**
    }
```

Comment: `GetCurrentFrame` returns a pointer, you cannot assign it to a reference.

Comment: Replacing `FrameData&` by `FrameData*` (and the following `data.`s by `data->`) should compile. Using a pointer is probably what you want in this situation.

Comment: Use `auto` for the local variable `data`. That'll deduce to the correct return type for you. That being said, as @Holt pointed out you can't assign a `pointer` to a `reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void CAnimation::Update(float deltaTime)
 {
        const FrameData* data = currentAnimation.second->GetCurrentFrame(); 
 }
```